# Py2app- Error building PyQt4 application on 10.7 Lion for 10.6 Snow Leopard (Symbol not found: _kMDItemDownloadedDate)

Tags: py2app

I have successfully built an open source application using py2app for 10.7 Lion.  However, when users try to open the application on 10.6 Snow Leopard, they get the following error:

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Applications/Mnemosyne.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/PyQt4/QTWebKit.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _kMDItemDownloadedDate
>
> Referenced from: 
>   /Applications/Mnemosyne.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/libQtWebKit.4.dylib

All of my dependencies are installed using MacPorts.  How can I fix this to allow Snow Leopard users to open the application as well?  This application is originally linux-based, so there should be no Lion-specific code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved this by installing Snow Leopard on a separate partition on my Mac and re-installing everything in Snow Leopard, then building the application there.  The Snow Leopard-built application runs fine in Snow Leopard, Lion, and Mountain Lion.